# How to know if any antivirus is installed on the machine or not?

Tags: anti-virus

I want to know if any antivirus software is installed or not...

I have observed that when we install any antivirus how it detects the presence
of any other antivirus if its pre-installed on that machine ?

Comment: it would help to know what OS you are running

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Vista and Windows 7 you can find out if antivirus software is installed by going to the Security Center

You can find the Security Center on Vista under Control Panel, and on Windows 7 it is the Action Centre.  In both cases you will see a screen somewhat like this one:

[image: Windows Security Center]

-=EDIT=-

Apologies, looks like the picture I found was a bit old and it's not named the "Solution Center", it's actually the "Action Center" which can be found by clicking on the little flag beside the clock in Windows 7...

Answer (score 0):

Use the EICAR test virus: http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm

Comment: Although most AV programs do, there are plenty that do not detect the EICAR test virus.